# How can I include related fields to the model serialization in django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have two models:

```
class User(models.Model):
  username = models.CharField()
```

and

```
class Post(models.Model):
  text = models.TextField()
  owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Using such serializer:

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer

class PostSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.Field(source='owner.id')

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['text', 'owner']
```

I get all posts with owners' ids. How can I modify serializer to get all posts with owner fialed containing the whole user model?

I tryied
    from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer

```
class PostSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.Field(source='owner')

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['text', 'owner']
```

but that only replaced id with username, not the whole model as I expected(because User's representation returns username field).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is to define UserSerializer extending ModelSerializer like that

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer

class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = ['id', 'username']
```

and then use it in PostSerializer:

```
from myapp import UserSerializer
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer

class PostSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    owner = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = PostModel
        fields = ['id', 'owner']
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `depth` option within your `ModelSerializer`'s `Meta` class:

```
class PostSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['text', 'owner']
        depth = 1
```

Also note that you don't need to include the `Author` field.

Docs [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#specifying-nested-serialization).

Comment: And about the solution. This is not exactly what I want. I want to expand the only field, not all fields to the given depth.